# How to get Width or ActualWith of the StackPanel.Children item

Tags: c#, wpf

How to get Width or ActualWith of the StackPanel.Children item?

```
foreach (var item in stackPanel1.Children)
{
 // item.Width ???              
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: @SLaks I tried item.Width but this property is not accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FrameworkElement` class since `ActualWidth` and `Width` belongs to this base class-

```
foreach (FrameworkElement item in stackPanel1.Children)
{
    double width = item.ActualWidth;
}
```